# Issues when I try to write in a new window with JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with the load of jQuery/JavaScript, I want to try writing in a new window after click a button with a specific data that are save in a the variable `event.target.dataset.serial`, but I do not why I can not write that data in the new Window

```js
bindNewWindow(handler) {
  $('.container p button').click((event) => {
    let position = this.newWindow.length;
    this.newWindow[position] = window.open('window.html', position, "width=1100, height=600, top=250, left=250, titlebar=yes, toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=yes");
    this.newWindow[position].addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      handler(event.target.dataset.serial)
    });
    this.newWindow[position].focus();
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
}

MostrarImagenVentanaNueva(imagen) {
  //Aquí iría la condición de si la ventana ya existe
  let position = this.newWindow.length - 1;
  let main = $(this.newWindow[position].document).find('main');
  main.empty();
  let container = $(`
            <img  width="250px" height="250px" src="${image.getURL()}"</p>
            <p>${image.getTitle()}</p>
            <p>${image.getDescription()}</p>
            <p>${image.getCoords()}</p>
            `);
  main.append(container);
  this.newWindow[position].document.body.scrollIntoView();
}
```

Comment: Errors in the console? Are you allowed to access "main" at all? What is the HTML of window.html?

Comment: Also parameters could be just`"width=1100,height=600,top=250,left=250,titlebar,location"`

Comment: and change append to .html then you can remove.empty

Comment: window.html it is the skeleton of the new Window that has a a few elements like navbar,.. And main it is the name of a tag in window.html where I want to put the data. There are not any error in console, only the data does not appear in the new window when I open it